# How to read values from property file in a JavaBean (domain class)?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a domain class and I want to read values from property file (autowiring messageSource wouldn't work here) so any ideas ?
I am using spring,hibernate
and here's a sample:

```
package com.myapp.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "domain")
public class MyDomain implements Serializable {

    private long entityId;
    private String domain="some_hardcoded_value" // need to read it from a property file;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public long getEntityId() {
        return entityId;
    }

    public void setEntityId(long entityId) {
        this.entityId = entityId;
    }

    public void setDomain(String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }

    @Column(name = "domain")
    public String getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }

}
```

Comment: I did not understand your question, why would auto wiring not work. Is it because its an entity class (and hence outside the scope of Spring AppContext). What is so special about reading from property file. Guess I am a bit lost.

Comment: i tried the messageSource but i always got exceptions  org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectcom.myapp.domain.MyDomain and (ContextLoader.java:220) - Context initialization failed and java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.myapp.domain.MyDomain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still don't understand the question, but I'll assume that you want to set bean properties from a properties file.

The other answers have shown how to get a Properties object from a .properties file (I'll show additional ways below), I will show you how to wire properties from it using Spring's `BeanWrapper` interface:

```
public static void wireBeanFromProperties(Object bean, Properties props){

    BeanWrapper wrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(bean);
    for(Entry<Object, Object> entry:props.entrySet()){
        String propertyName = entry.getKey().toString();
        if(wrapper.isWritableProperty(propertyName)){
            wrapper.setPropertyValue(propertyName, entry.getValue());
        }
    }

}
```

Or, if you know for sure that all properties from the properties file can be mapped to this bean properties of the class:

```
public static void wireBeanFromProperties(final Object bean,
    final Properties props){
    final BeanWrapper wrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(bean);
    // will throw an exception if the Properties object
    // contains any unknown keys
    wrapper.setPropertyValues(props);
}
```

**Reference: [5.4. Bean manipulation and the BeanWrapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans)**

---

Actually, the Spring-specific ways to load resources from the classpath use [the `Resource` mechanism](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html)

```
InputStream str = new ClassPathResource("classpath:some.properties")
                      .getInputStream();
```

The nice part is that you can wire both InputStreams and Resources easily from XML using the `classpath:` syntax:

Java Code

```
private InputStream stream;
private Resource resource;
public void setStream(InputStream stream){
    this.stream = stream;
}
public void setResource(Resource resource){
    this.resource = resource;
}
```

property wiring:

```
<bean class="MyClass">
    <property name="stream" value="classpath:file1.properties" />
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:file2.properties" />
</bean>
```

---

If you just want to initialize a static final field, here's how to do it:

```
private static final String DOMAIN;
static{
    InputStream inputStream=null;
    try{
        inputStream = new ClassPathResource("classpath:some.properties")
                          .getInputStream();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(inputStream);
        String key = "your.property";
        if(!props.containsKey(key))
            throw new IllegalStateException("Property not found");
        DOMAIN= props.getProperty(key);
    } catch(IOException e){
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }finally{
        // apache commons / IO
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: simply what i want to do in my JavaBean class is that i want to read the following property value from a property file.... private String domain="some_hardcoded_value" // need to read it from a property file;

Comment: it's not a constant, it's a variable but has a default value, and i want to initialize the default value, so i should remove the final, right ?

Comment: @sword101 I'm not sure I'd call it a good practice, but: right

Answer (score 0):

Beside everything, you can always do,

```
Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("some.properties")
```

But I am still curious what you want to read in your `Entity`, from a property file.

Comment: I want to read some hard-coded default values for the properties. and what is the difference between this way and using the MessageSource, is this way has issues or something?

Comment: @sword101: Sorry, but I have no idea what `MessageSource` is. I think its pretty okay to do that like this.

Comment: but the code above returns an input stream not the string value

Comment: @sword101: Yes, you can instantiate `Properties` class using this input stream. Then you can use that like, `props.get("property.name")`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Ansari's code

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load (Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().
         getResourceAsStream("some.properties"));

p.list(System.out);  // or p.get("name")   --> name=value.
```

After searching in internet i found below

```
<!--Bean to load properties file -->  

<bean id="placeholderConfig" 
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">    
<property name="location" value="classpath:config.properties">  
<!--reads config.properties file-->
```

Please read this article http://www.zparacha.com/how-to-read-properties-file-in-spring/

Comment: see my second answer reading from classpath:config.properties