# How do I wire a property without Spring?

Tags: spring, properties

So I'm trying to cut back on Spring dependance buy using @Inject etc. Problem is that I can't figure out how to wire in a String property from a properties file. Clue? Is there an alternative to @Value?

Comment: Think I just found the answer: https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-named-and-inject-jsr-330-annotation-example

Comment: Look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733401/how-to-read-values-from-property-file-in-a-javabean-domain-class) to find a good solution to that problem.

Comment: Turns out I just had my syntax wrong. I mean it's a spring boot project after all. I'm jus trying to stay as agnostic as I can within reason.